# Mongodb Aggregation and sum many fields

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to perform a mongodb aggregation and there are so many fields I need to sum. Is there an easy way to "$sum" many fields of a document? Below is my document structure:

```
{date: "20170331", field_A: 10, field_B: 20, field_C: 30, ...}
{date: "20170331", field_A: 11, field_B: 21, field_C: 31, ...}
{date: "20170630", field_A: 12, field_B: 22, field_C: 32, ...}
{date: "20170630", field_A: 13, field_B: 23, field_C: 33, ...}
```

I want to group by "date" and sum all the fields for each group. I know I can achieve this by sum all the fields one by one:

```
{$group: {
     _id: "$date",
     field_A_sum:{$sum: "$field_A"},
     field_B_sum:{$sum: "$field_B"},
     field_C_sum:{$sum: "$field_C"},
     ......
}}
```

But there are so many fields I need to sum, write the code in this way is almost impossible. So is there an easy way to sum hundreds of fields?

Or is there any function I can use to loop each field and sum them?

Thanks

Comment: You have to specify each field in the `$group` stage. No other way

Comment: Get the list of fields you want to sum and then write a snippet which can generate this query for you. Also if the number of fields are like in 1000s you might want to break your queries into batches.